# Properties values stored after static function call

Tags: swift

Consider following code:

```
struct Foo {
    static var bar = 0
    static func test() {
        Self.bar = 2 + Self.bar
        print(Self.bar)
    }
}
```

---

```
Foo.test() // prints 2
Foo.test() // prints 4
Foo.test() // prints 6
```

I'm confused, i'm not storing instance `Foo` in variable, so why does `bar` value persist after subsequent calls? I expected it to be 2 every time function call

Does it means when we call static methods (or change properties values) on Type (instead of instance), it stored "somewhere", rather then calculate every time from initial state?

Comment: Yes, it is a stored value.

Comment: Not related to your question but writing Self prefix on a static method of the same class is redundant. Why not simply `bar += 2`? And `print(bar)`

Comment: A static property belongs to the type. Imagine `Foo` as a (single) template object. `bar` is part of the template and is available in all instances.

Comment: @LeoDabus yes it's redundant, did add it for clarity

Comment: @vadian it's like somewhere in Memory is instance of "Foo" class which properties you can change and access anywhere?

Comment: Not *like*. The declared struct Foo has a place in memory including the static members/properties. And it's not an instance, it's the template or blueprint. You have to access it anyway when you are going to create an instance which creates a independent copy of the blueprint.

Comment: @vadian thank you, so in fact it is the same as singleton object in that way? Like i can add bunch of properties and take/change their values from anywhere like global constants?

Comment: Yes, but it's only recommended if the properties have a strong relationship to the type.

Comment: You can think of static properties as instance properties of `Foo` itself (not an instance of `Foo`), which is an instance of the metatype `Foo.Type`. Some languages (e.g. Ruby) make this pretty explicit, where class methods don't actually exist, but are in fact instance methods of a class itself (which is an instance of the `Class` class).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your confusion is a common one, especially for those new to the concept of static properties and methods in Swift. Let's break it down:

#### Static Properties and Methods

- When you define a `static` property (or `class` property for reference types), it belongs to the *type* itself and not to any specific instance of that type. This means there's only one copy of that property in memory for that type.
- When you call a `static` method, it operates on the type itself, not on any specific instance of the type.

In your example, `bar` is a static property of `Foo`. When you modify it using `Foo.test()`, you're updating that single, shared copy of `bar` in memory.

#### Why Does `bar` Persist?

The reason `bar` retains its value between calls to `Foo.test()` is because you're modifying the same `bar` every time. It isn't re-initialized to `0` with each call since you're not creating a new instance of `Foo` with each call. Instead, you're operating directly on the `Foo` type.

To visualize this better, consider the type (like `Foo`) as a kind of "singleton object" regarding static properties and methods. It retains and maintains its state across calls.

#### Comparing with Instance Properties

For contrast, look at instance properties:

```swift
struct FooInstance {
    var bar = 0
    mutating func test() {
        self.bar = 2 + self.bar
        print(self.bar)
    }
}

var foo1 = FooInstance()
foo1.test()  // prints 2

var foo2 = FooInstance()
foo2.test()  // prints 2
```

With instance properties, each new **FooInstance** you create starts with its **bar** property initialized to **0**. But with the **static bar** in your original example, it's initialized to 0 just once and then maintains whatever value you set it to across calls.